# raspberry pi picamera - image comparison

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

Im trying to detect movement in between 2 pictures taken from the raspberry pi picamera. i'm doing this by comparing de raw pixeldata with eachother. 
Below is a simple script which i'm using to test the comparison.

```
import picamera
import datetime
from fractions import Fraction
import time
import numpy as np

oldImage = np.empty((48, 64, 3))
newImage = np.empty((48, 64, 3))
color_offset = 25

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (64,48)
    camera.start_preview()
    time.sleep(2)

    camera.capture(oldImage, "rgb")
    time.sleep(5)
    camera.capture(newImage, "rgb")

    x = 0
    y = 0
    diff = 0

    while(x < np.size(newImage, 0)):
        while(y < np.size(newImage, 1)):
            val1 = newImage[x, y, 0] + newImage[x, y, 1] + newImage[x, y, 2]
            val2 = oldImage[x, y, 0] + oldImage[x, y, 1] + oldImage[x, y, 2]
            print(val1)
            print(val2)
            pd = abs(val2 - val1)
            print(pd)

            if(pd > color_offset):
                diff += 1
            y +=1
        x += 1
        y=0

    print(str(diff))
```

In the script i start the camera, take the first picture, wait a few seconds, take the second picture and calculate the difference. However evertime i run this script, the "val1" variable is always 0.0.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The output would be printed 3072 times - it's always zero? You could try with even smaller image data that you can control, e.g. a 4x4 image. This would even fit inside the source code and it could be an [mcve]...

Comment: Yhis the oupout was printed over 3000 times and i didn't see a single one that wasn't zero with a quick scroll. The picamera only alows for a resolution down to 32x32 pixels. But lowering the resolution definitely changed something, val1 isn't always 0.0 anymore. Weird but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

So with a 2x2 "image", your color value addition

```
import numpy as np

newImage = np.array([[[0,0,0], [1,0,0]], [[0,1,0], [0,1,1]]])

x = 0
y = 0
while(x < np.size(newImage, 0)):
    while(y < np.size(newImage, 1)):
        val1 = newImage[x, y, 0] + newImage[x, y, 1] + newImage[x, y, 2]
        print(val1)
        y +=1
    x += 1
    y = 0
```

produces

```
0
1
1
2
```

as I would expect.

What result do you expect? Is your data OK (provide sample data)?

Comment: BTW I strongly suspect that NumPy has functions for summing and "diffing" arrays...

Comment: Changing the resolution fixed this problem but there is something else wrong with the data, or maybe i don't understand how images work. The added up pixel values are always extremly high or extremly low. They are in notated like this: x.xe(-)xxx.

Comment: @emericw https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#E-notation Maybe NumPy handles integer image data incorrectly and it needs conversion into NumPy arrays? I don't know.

Comment: Initializing the array with a uint8 datatype did the trick. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @emericw What do you mean: "anyway"?